# Blocks is not showing up

Tags: 7, blocks

I am facing trouble while configuring a block. The block I configure is not showing up onmy website. I am using drupal 7 and the Touch theme. Here are the steps I do:
- in REGION SETTINGS i have selected "Highlighted"
- Visibility settings is:
 - pages (Only the listed pages) [http://example.com/news]
- Content types
 - Show block for specific content types> [Publish A News]
- Roles
 - I have made no changes here
- Users have not been set
Any ideas why the block is not showing up?

Comment: The pages text area should contain a relative path (so just 'news') have you tried that?

Comment: its not working :( see this screenshot http://i.stack.imgur.com/Uwt5v.png any idea?

Comment: Try it without the quotes

Comment: i did it but not worked :(

Comment: Is the highlighted region definitely being printed to the page in your theme?

Comment: i have moved it to Content here is the screenshot http://i.stack.imgur.com/DkivK.png , but still not works.,,,

Comment: I guess the block is empty in that context then, so doesn't get displayed. There's no other good reason why it wouldn't show

Comment: "Context" do you mean block body? else what is Context

Comment: can you get it working without specifying page .. just to check if the block is displaying correctly!

Comment: @Serjas okay now its showing in every page of my website perfectly ... now what?

Comment: okay now it works ...... :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify your node name. for example: you want to display your block on www.yoursitename/news page. Then you need to specify only **news** in that box. Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but use node/11 - or what ever the node is of that page.

Comment: Where would the user put this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the pages that block want to show in "pages (Only the listed pages" without any quote or using absolute path. for example: you want to display your block on `www.yoursitename.com/news` page  just need enter `news` in that box without any quote and absolute URL.